# trying to talk to email server via SMTP with c program

Tags: c, sockets, email, smtp

I'm trying to create a little C program that allow me to talk to mail server via smtp, I created this little program:

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


// Need to link with Ws2_32.lib, Mswsock.lib, and Advapi32.lib

#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
#define DEFAULT_PORT "25"
#define DEFAULT_ADDRESS "smtp.live.com"
int __cdecl main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    struct addrinfo *result = NULL,
                    *ptr = NULL,
                    hints;
    char messaggio[100];
    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    int iResult;
    int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;

    while(1){// Initialize Winsock
        iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
        if (iResult != 0) {
            printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
            return 1;
        }

        ZeroMemory( &hints, sizeof(hints) );
        hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
        hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
        hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

        // Resolve the server address and port
        iResult = getaddrinfo(DEFAULT_ADDRESS, DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
        if ( iResult != 0 ) {
            printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

    // Attempt to connect to an address until one succeeds
        for(ptr=result; ptr != NULL ;ptr=ptr->ai_next) {

            // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
            ConnectSocket = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype, 
                ptr->ai_protocol);
            if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
                printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
                WSACleanup();
                return 1;
            }

            // Connect to server.
            iResult = connect( ConnectSocket, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen);
            if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                closesocket(ConnectSocket);
                ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
                continue;
            }
            break;
        }

        freeaddrinfo(result);

        if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            printf("Unable to connect to server!\n");
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

        printf("messaggio: ");
        gets(messaggio);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("%s\n", messaggio);
        // Send an initial buffer
        iResult = send( ConnectSocket, messaggio, (int)strlen(messaggio), 0 );
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(ConnectSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

        printf("Bytes Sent: %ld\n", iResult);

        // shutdown the connection since no more data will be sent
        iResult = shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_SEND);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            printf("shutdown failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(ConnectSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

        // Receive until the peer closes the connection
      //  do {

            iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
                if ( iResult > 0 ){
                printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);
                printf("messaggio: %s\n", recvbuf);}
            else if ( iResult == 0 )
                printf("Connection closed\n");
            else
                printf("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
       // } while( iResult > 0 );
        // cleanu
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

When I launch it, it does connect to the smtp server, then send the message (for example Hello message) and receive 220 reply code meaning that the services is ready. When I continue typing command it does continue to send me 220 code without going forward, and when I miss type a command it just crush.

may any of you please help me?

p.s. I take no credit for code, I just modified some socket client documentation of microsoft to talk to smtp.live.com and apparently it does work...

---

[EDIT] x2:

ok, thanks to Remy Lebeau i apparently managed to resolve those problem, hope this is the last one.

edited code:

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


// Need to link with Ws2_32.lib, Mswsock.lib, and Advapi32.lib

#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
#define DEFAULT_PORT "25"
#define DEFAULT_ADDRESS "smtp.live.com"

int __cdecl main(int argc, char **argv){
    WSADATA wsaData;
    SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    struct addrinfo *result = NULL,
    *ptr = NULL,
    hints;
    char messaggio[100];
    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    int iResult;
    int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;
    int success = 1;

    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData); // Initialize Winsock
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

    ZeroMemory( &hints, sizeof(hints) );
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    iResult = getaddrinfo(DEFAULT_ADDRESS, DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result); // Resolve the server address and port
    if ( iResult != 0 ) {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    for(ptr=result; ptr != NULL ;ptr=ptr->ai_next) {  // Attempt to connect to an address until one succeeds

        ConnectSocket = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype, ptr->ai_protocol);
        if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

        iResult = connect( ConnectSocket, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen);  //Connect to server.
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            closesocket(ConnectSocket);
            ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
            continue;
        }

        break;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("Unable to connect to server!\n");
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    while(success){

        printf("messaggio: ");
        scanf(" %[^\n]", messaggio);
        printf("%s\n", messaggio);

        iResult = send( ConnectSocket, strcat(messaggio,"\r\n"), (int)strlen(messaggio)+2, 0 );  //Send an initial buffer
        if (iResult < 0 || iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(ConnectSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            system("PAUSE");
            return 1;
        }
        printf("Bytes Sent: %ld\n", iResult);

        do{  //riceve tutto il possibile dal server
            iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen-1, 0);
            recvbuf[iResult]='\0';
            if ( iResult > 0 ){
                printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);
                printf("messaggio: %s\n", recvbuf);
            }
            else{
                printf("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
                success=0;
            }
        }while(recvbuf[iResult-3]=='\r'&& recvbuf[iResult-2]=='\n');

        printf("stop receive\n");
    }
    iResult = shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_SEND);
    closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Now it does take my command and it does respond, i do `helo`, `mail from: <mail>` and `to: <mail>` and at this point it says: "530 (code for auth problem) Must issue a STARTTLS command first.

Is there a way to resolve this? i've to encode my sended command, is there a way to do this with winsock?

Did i almost got the point of the problem or it isn't this the problem?

Comment: 1. You shouldn't use `gets()`, which has unavoidable risk of buffer overrun. 2. `fflush(stdin);` invokes *undefined behavior*, so do not use it. 3. You invoked *undefined behavor* by passing data having wrong type to `printf()`: `%ld` cals for `long`, but `iResult` has type `int`.

Comment: The problem is because you connect the server, send something and receive something, then *you disconnect from the server and connect again*. Instead of that, proceed using current session without disconnectiong and reconnectiong.

Comment: You are also calling `WSAStartup()` and `WSACleanup()` on each loop iteration. They should only be called once, at program start and program end, respectively.

Comment: Error 10058 is `WSAESHUTDOWN`, which DOES NOT mean the **server** shut down the connection, it means **you** shut it down: "*The socket has been shut down; it is not possible to send on a socket after `shutdown` has been invoked with `how` set to `SD_SEND` or `SD_BOTH`*". If the **server** had shut down the connection, you would be getting a different error instead. In the code you have shown, `shutdown()` is commented out, so there is no possible way that `send()` can be failing with `WSAESHUTDOWN`.

Comment: That said, you are not breaking the loop if `recv()` fails. And your 2nd `printf()` when `iResult > 0` is assuming that `recvbuf` is null-terminated, which is not actually the case. You need to take `iResult` into account, eg: `iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen-1, 0); ... recvbuf[iResult] = 0; printf("messaggio: %s\n", recvbuf);` or `iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0); ... printf("messaggio: %.*s\n", iResult, recvbuf);`

Comment: And don't forget that TCP is a byte stream, there is no guarantee that you will send an entire command in a single `send()` call, or that you will receive an entire response in a single `recv()` call. You have to keep sending until you have nothing left to send, and you have to keep reading until you encounter the `\r\n` that terminates each line. And you also have to take into account that an SMTP response may have multiple lines, so you have to actually parse the responses to detect that. The actual format of the responses is outlined in [RFC 5321](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5321).

Comment: thanks for that documentation, i managed to solve a lot of problems, i think this is the last one :)

Comment: First, you did not correctly implement what I said, not even close. Your reading and sending logic is still very broken, even if you think it "works" (which it won't always). Second, `To:` is not a valid SMTP command, the correct command is `RCPT TO:`. Third, "*Must issue a STARTTLS command first*" is pretty self-explanatory. You have sent an SMTP command over an unsecure connection and the server requires it to be sent over a secure connection instead (like when sending authentication credentials in plain text).

Comment: The [`STARTTLS`](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3207) command is used to activate a new SSL/TLS session to secure an unsecure connection. You can use libraries like OpenSSL, or Microsoft's SChannel API, to implement the actual SSL/TLS on your socket.  That is outside the scope of this question. If you want help with implementing SSL/TLS, there are plenty of books and tutorials on that subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code logic is incomplete for an SMTP client.

TCP is a byte stream.  There is no guarantee that you will be able to send an entire command in a single `send()` call, or that you will be able to receive an entire response in a single `recv()` call. You have to keep sending until you have nothing left to send, and you have to keep reading until there is nothing more to read.  Which, in the case of SMTP, means when you encounter the `\r\n` that terminates each line.

Once you have your underlying socket I/O working, you are still not implementing the actual SMTP protocol.  You are just throwing arbitrary data at the server and reading whatever arbitrary data it returns.  SMTP has rules that you need to take into account.  For example, an SMTP server sends a greeting before accepting commands.  You are not reading that greeting.  Also, an SMTP response may have 1 or more lines, so you have to parse each line individually (the format is outlined in [RFC 5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321)) to discover how many lines need to be read.  Keep reading until you encounter the last line of a response.  Don't send the next command until the previous response has been fully read (unless you want to implement [SMTP pipelining](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2920), which I won't get into here).

As for the "*Must issue a STARTTLS command first*" error, that is pretty self-explanatory. You sent an SMTP command over an unsecure connection, but the server wants that command to be sent over a secure connection instead (such as when sending an [`AUTH`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4954) command containing authentication credentials in plain text).  The [`STARTTLS`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3207) command is used to activate a new SSL/TLS session to secure a connection that is currently unsecure.

You can use libraries like [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org), or APIs like Microsoft's [SChannel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380123.aspx), to implement the actual SSL/TLS on top of your socket. That is outside the scope of this question. If you want help with implementing SSL/TLS, there are plenty of books and tutorials on that subject.

With all of that said, try something more like this instead:

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
#pragma command(lib, "mswsock.lib")
//#pragma command(lib, "advapi32.lib")

#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512

#define DEFAULT_PORT "25"
#define DEFAULT_ADDRESS "smtp.live.com"

char *recvbuf = NULL;
int recvbuflen = 0;
int recvbufused = 0;

int sendData(SOCKET s, char *buffer, int buflen)
{
    int iResult;

    while (buflen > 0)
    {
        // TODO: if the connection is secure, encrypt the data being sent...

        iResult = send(s, buffer, buflen, 0);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            return -1;
        }

        buffer += iResult;
        buflen -= iResult;
    }

    return 0;
}

int sendLine(SOCKET s, char *line)
{
    int iResult = sendData(s, line, strlen(line));
    if (iResult == 0)
        iResult = sendData(s, "\r\n", 2);
    return iResult;
}

int readLine(SOCKET s, char **line)
{
    char buf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    int iResult;
    int offset = 0, len, total;
    char *p;

    *line = NULL;

    do
    {
        // check if the line terminator is already in the buffer
        p = memchr(recvbuf+offset, '\n', recvbufused-offset);
        if (p != NULL)
        {
            ++p;
            total = (p - recvbuf);

            // check if the line terminator is actually "\r\n"
            len = total - 1;
            if ((len > 0) && (recvbuf[len-1] == '\r'))
                --len;

            // extract the line and remove it from the buffer
            *line = malloc(len+1);
            if (*line == NULL)
            {
                printf("Unable to allocate memory! Bytes: %d\n", len+1);
                return -1;
            }

            memcpy(*line, recvbuf, len);
            (*line)[len] = 0;

            memmove(recvbuf, recvbuf+total, recvbufused-total);
            recvbufused -= total;

            printf("%s\n", *line);
            return len;
        }

        // line terminator is not in the buffer, keep reading

        // do not search the buffer that was already searched
        offset = recvbufused;

        // read more data from the socket
        iResult = recv(s, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);
        if (iResult <= 0)
        {
            if (iResult == 0)
                printf("server closed the connection\n");
            else
                printf("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());

            break;
        }

        // TODO: if the connection is secure, decrypt the data that was received...

        // if the buffer is too small for the new data, grow it
        if ((recvbufused+iResult) > recvbuflen)
        {
            len = (recvbufused+iResult) + DEFAULT_BUFLEN;
            p = realloc(recvbuf, len);
            if (p == NULL)
            {
                printf("Unable to allocate memory! Bytes: %d\n", len);
                break;
            }

            recvbuf = p;
            recvbuflen = len;
        }

        // now add the data to the buffer
        memcpy(recvbuf+recvbufused, buf, iResult);
        recvbufused += iResult;
    }
    while (1);

    return -1;
}

int readResponse(SOCKET s)
{
    char *line, term[5];
    int len, code = 0;

    // read the first line
    len = readLine(s, &line);
    if (len == -1)
        return -1;

    // check if the response has multiple lines
    if ((len > 3) && (line[3] == '-'))
    {
        // keep reading until the last line is received
        memcpy(term, line, 3);
        term[3] = ' ';
        term[4] = '\0';

        do
        {
            free(line);
            len = readLine(s, &line);
            if (len == -1)
                return -1;
        }
        while ((len > 3) && (strncmp(line, term, 4) != 0));
    }

    // now extract the response code and return it

    if (len > 3) line[3] = '\0';
    code = strtol(line, NULL, 10);
    free(line);

    if (code == 0)
        return -1;

    return code;
}

int __cdecl main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    struct addrinfo hints, *result, *ptr;
    char messaggio[100];
    int iResult;

    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0)
    {
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

    ZeroMemory( &hints, sizeof(hints) );
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    // Resolve the server address and port
    iResult = getaddrinfo(DEFAULT_ADDRESS, DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    if (iResult != 0)
    {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Attempt to connect to an address until one succeeds
    for(ptr=result; ptr != NULL; ptr=ptr->ai_next)
    {
        ConnectSocket = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype, ptr->ai_protocol);
        if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
            break;
        }

        //Connect to server.
        iResult = connect(ConnectSocket, ptr->ai_addr, ptr->ai_addrlen);
        if (iResult == 0)
            break;

        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Unable to connect to server!\n");
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Connected to server\n");

    // read the greeting
    iResult = readResponse(ConnectSocket);
    if (iResult == 220)
    {
        do
        {
            // ask the user for a command
            printf("messaggio: ");
            if (!fgets(messaggio, sizeof(messaggio), stdin))
                break;

            // remove the line terminator if present
            iResult = strlen(messaggio);
            if ((iResult > 0) && (messaggio[iResult-1] == '\n'))
                messaggio[iResult-1] = '\0';
    
            // send the command
            iResult = sendLine(ConnectSocket, messaggio);
            if (iResult == -1)
                break;

            // read the response
            iResult = readResponse(ConnectSocket);
            if (iResult == -1)
                break;

            // need to stop now?
            if (strcmp(messaggio, "QUIT") == 0)
                break;

            // need to turn on SSL/TLS now?
            if ((strcmp(messaggio, "STARTTLS") == 0) && (iResult == 220))
            {
                // TODO: activate SSL/TLS, stop if failed...
            }
        }
        while(1);
    }

    shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_SEND);
    do
    {
        iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, messaggio, sizeof(messaggio), 0);
    }
    while (iResult > 0);

    closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    WSACleanup();

    free(recvbuf);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I made some adjustments to the code above, and now it works when I try it.